# TOP and ORDER BY sql error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select the last record from a table in MySQL using PHP. I believe I have an SQL error. Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT TOP 1 id FROM `table` ORDER BY id DESC
```

If this is valid and I actually have a PHP error, tell me.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

you have an invalid sql syntax. use **[LIMIT](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)** instead

try this:

```
SELECT id 
FROM table 
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

the `TOP` clause works on MSSQL server.

Comment: @Markasoftware: Not if you switch to SQL Server. :)

Comment: @PeterMajeed you are correct. but the op tagged MySQL not MS :)

Comment: This does not work, you can't use limit in sub query

Comment: but if we want to print the third highest value, how do we do it?

Answer (score 12):

A simpler and more DBMS-agnostic approach would be:

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS id
FROM table
```

That's only if you want *just* the `id` field, otherwise if you tried to SELECT other columns, it wouldn't return matching data to the `id` field and you would instead have to use:

```
SELECT id, otherfields, ..., ...
FROM table
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table)
```

Answer (score 0):

*This will work To find the last record if you are not looking to use limit*

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Products ORDER BY id desc
```

*This will work To find the last record specifying column name if you are not looking to use limit*

```
SELECT TOP 1 id FROM Products ORDER BY id desc
```

*Else*

```
SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```