# C# and SQL TOP query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

So I want to get TOP 5 results from my table (phpmyadmin) using C# in WPF. I have this code:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT TOP 5 * FROM users", Conn);
```

You have an error in your sql syntax check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for right syntax to use near ' 5 * FROM users' at line 1.

I don't know what is wrong in this, I checked few sites and everywhere is same syntax.

Comment: MySQL uses `LIMIT`, not `TOP`.

Comment: @CodeCaster You should make that an answer. `TOP` is `MSSQL` and `Access` syntax. Or duplicate it. :)

Comment: When you use top/limit you might want to use an order by clause too, otherwise you'll just get random rows as the data returned is an unordered set.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076568/top-and-order-by-sql-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already commented, in MySQL you can't use TOP, and you should use LIMIT instead:

```
SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Yes this works, didn't thought that top wouldn't work.